# Is there a rule of thumb for when to use JSON objects instead of arrays with a 'name' key?

Tags: arrays, json, object, kubernetes

What reasons might one prefer the `with_object` or the `with_array` options below?

```
{
  "with_array": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "key": "value"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "key": "value"
    }
  ],
  "with_object": {
    "foo": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "bar": {
      "key": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

Real world example: Why is the environment variable spec in this Kubernetes manifest using an array of `name` and `value` keys?

```
pods/inject/envars.yaml 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

From [Define an environment variable for a container](http://%20https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container)

Comment: It **really** depends on what you're going to do with the data.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order you should use array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to three questions can help finding which of the two is more appropriate:

[image: questions to determine structure]